# Webtop2sd on Driod Bionic

Tags: webtop, bionic

I am not able to boot the custom webtop. When I boot webtop, I just get the standard version with no ability to install programs, run LXTerm, etc...

I am running a rooted stock Bionic 902
I have applied the HDMI webtop hack
I ran webtop2sd
I ran the custom busybox installer
I applied the e mbm.tar.bz2 patch
I reran the webtop2sd installer.

No change in the webtop that booted after any of those steps.

My diagnostics for webtop2sd is:
version: 2.0.1
Mount executable Version webtop2sd/2.0.0
Custom busybox installed: Y
Webtop configurator version: 33
Currently mounted webtops: webtop, mmcblk0p2

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

mbm's patch just enables the gnome terminal in Webtop, so that you can then access other things through command line.  try Ctrl-alt-t.  that should bring up the Terminal built in to Ubuntu.  can you link the mbm.tar.bz2? if you have a working one, which you seem to, i cant find one anywhere! thanks!